# What if All Actions call same function in Asp.net MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

All, In my application design, Some the actions of Controller classes will call the same method firstly whenever it was called. the code snippet looks like below . please review it .thanks.

```
public class Controller1 : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Action1()
        {
            FunctionA(); //This function must be called firstly.This function is defined somewhere. 
            return View("a1");
        }

        public ActionResult Action2()
        {
            FunctionA(); 
            return View("a2");
        }

    }

public class Controller2 : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Action3()
        {
            FunctionA(); 
            return View("a3");
        }

        public ActionResult Action4()
        {
            FunctionB(); 
            return View("a4");
        }

    }
```

In current case ,  `Action1`,`Action2` in `Controller1` and `Action3` in `Controller2` will call the same `FunctionA()` , Based on the DRY theory, It is better to define a base controller or method something , I don't know how to make it in Asp.net MVC4. Please help me .thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only you can answer this question because essentially the answer is dependant on *your* design.

If your `FunctionA` method is specific to that controller then you could introduce a base class. However, you could alternatively use a helper class or even just an extension method (if it's generic enough) to achieve your DRY architecture.

In terms of how to call it in your action, if it must be run *before* the action is executed then I would suggest introducing a custom [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) which you can use to decorate each action e.g.

```
public class Controller1 : Controller
{
    [FunctionAAttribute]
    public ActionResult Action1()
    {
        return View("a1");
    }

    [FunctionAAttribute]
    public ActionResult Action2()
    {
        return View("a2");
    }
}
```

Or if it has to be run before *every* action on that particular controller, just decorate the controller e.g.

```
[FunctionAAttribute]
public class Controller1 : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Action1()
    {
        return View("a1");
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: `Attribute` is nice . Because it can decorate whatever you want class or action. so that can keep these things have the same behavior .

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite as simple as that. If they simply share some code it doesn't necessarily mean they should have a common base class that implements that functionality. You're thinking about details in code to drive your interface.

I can't answer the question without knowing more about the specifics, but as long as the code they are all using is in one place, you're halfway in the right direction.

Comment: Actually,I want all these actions return the same ViewBag property, for example `ViewBag.UserList` which contain a user list, And I have a shared view like `_layout.cshtml` use this `ViewBag.UserList` property by default. thanks